# check if windows service exists vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have the following code to check if a Windows service exists but it keeps throwing an exception if the service does not exist.

```
Dim controller As New ServiceController("test")
If controller.Status = Nothing Then
    Label2.Text = ""
Else
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Service found")
End If
```

What I would like is do nothing if not found and add to listbox if found.

Comment: (1) *What* is the exception? (2) Is your code running as an administrator? Querying service status may be a restricted operation.

Comment: Hi, Exception is "service not found" and I am running in admin mode

Answer (score 4):

That may be by design since ServiceController is meant to "connect to and control the behavior of existing services" (c.f. [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)). Reading [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.status%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) the `Status` property is supposed to throw an `InvalidOperationException` if the service does not exist.

What you could do is use the GetServices() [method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hde9d63a%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb) to list the services on the machine and see if the thing you are looking for exists - perhaps something like:

```
Dim servicesButNotDevices As ServiceController() = ServiceController.GetServices()

For Each service As ServiceController In servicesButNotDevices
    If service.ServiceName = "my service name" Then 'May also use DispalyName property depending on your use case
        'Put in list box
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

If you didn't want to catch and handle the exception

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried this but it didn't seem to pick up services that do exist?

Comment: @DaE there may be a difference between the `ServiceName` and the `DisplayName` properties depending on what you're searching for. For example, running this on my machine I have a service with a `ServiceName` of "AdobeARMservice" but it has a `DisplayName` of "Adobe Acrobat Update Service"...so you might want to switch properties depending on whether you're looking for the friendly name of the service or not...

Answer (score 2):

According to [the `ServiceController` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3ket56y.aspx), this is the expected behavior. If the service exists, the constructor makes a `ServiceController` instance that provides an interface to control the service. If the service does not exist, there is nothing to do so the constructor throws an `ArgumentException`.

The following code should do what you need:

```
Try
    Dim controller As New ServiceController("test")
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Service found")
Catch ex As ArgumentException
    Label2.Text = ""
End Try
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did try this but it seems to add "service found" with any value added to the **ServiceController("test")**

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for everyones input on this.

I used the idea from NKVU but tweaked it a little:

```
For Each service As ServiceController In ServiceController.GetServices()
                Dim serviceName As String = service.ServiceName
                If serviceName = "mmg" Then
                    ListBox1.Items.Add(serviceName)
                End If
            Next
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Shared Function GetService() As ServiceProcess.ServiceController
    Try
        Dim Services = (From f In ServiceProcess.ServiceController.GetServices Select f Where f.ServiceName = "BilgiSoft").ToList
        If Services.Count = 1 Then
            Return Services(0)
            Exit Function
        Else
            Return Nothing
            Exit Function
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return Nothing
        Exit Function
    End Try
End Function
```